# What methods are triggered when the rotation changes?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I've looked into [viewWillTransitionToSize](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransitiontosize) but it doesn't really declare what it actually does when this fire. Are these methods accessible somehow?

For example I have ScrollView with a contentSize set to 1000 after async call is finished.

If I log this value it's correct but my ScrollView is rendered to the height of 667.

But when I tilt the screen and back (to landscape mode and back to portrait) the ScrollView gets reloaded and the height is correctly set to 1000.

So I figured that the viewWillTransitionToSize must have some method to rerender views?

Comment: I think you are looking for the viewWillLayoutSubivews method.

Comment: what is actual height of your scrollView? 667? and what do you want it's size in portrait and landscape??

Comment: The ScrollView on load is 667, after async call is completed I set it to the new height of 1000. When I log the new height it's correctly set to 1000 but it's rendered at 667. On orientation change it renders at 1000.